# The projection of density 1 point on a rectifiable set.

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

This post has also been posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228062/the-projection-of-density-1-point-on-a-rectifiable-set). Please see the comment on the linked page, useful information!

Let $\Gamma\subset \mathbb R^N$ be $\mathcal H^{N-1}$-[rectifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set). Then we know that $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in \Gamma$ has density $1$. In particular, let $\nu(x)\in \mathcal S^{N-1}$ be a vector at $x\in \Gamma$ and normal to $\Gamma$, and $Q(x,r)$ be a cube centered at $x$ with side length $r>0$ and two faces normal to $\nu(x)$, we have
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal H^{N-1}(Q(x,r)\cap \Gamma)}{r^{N-1}}=1
$$
for $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ a.e. $x\in\Gamma$.

---

> My question: Fix $x\in \Gamma$ satisfies above. Let $T_x$ denote the hyperplane normal to $\nu(x)$ and passing through $x$. Then, do we have
>   $$
> \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\mathcal H^{N-1}(\mathbb P_x[Q(x,r)\cap \Gamma])}{r^{N-1}}=1?
> $$

Where $\mathbb P_x$ is the projection operator which projects $x\in \Gamma$ onto the hyperplane $T_x$. For example, if $T_x = \{x_N=0\}$, then $\mathbb P_x(x)=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{N-1},0)$ where $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_N)$.

PS: I know for instance that 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}\lfloor\left(\frac{\Gamma-x}{r}\right)\to \mathcal H^{N-1}\lfloor \mathbb P_x
$$
weakly as $r\to 0$. I think I may conclude from this statement but still...feel there is still a gap...

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Crossposted to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/228062/the-projection-of-density-1-point-on-a-rectifiable-set

Comment: @LukasGeyer Sorry I should make a link on my post to MOF. Done!